# Views default background - when should you write @null?

Tags: android, view, colors, background

I was wondering which views have background @null by default and on which views it's recommended to add it in order to reduce the number of overlays? For example in the following construct:

```
relativelayout
    relativelayout
        framelayout
            view
```

If I want a white background (where only one view in the xml has this background - no overlaying of white on white), and I only define 'background white' for the highest relativelayout - will all the other layouts have a background "layer" or not (if none is specified)?

Comment: Could this article be of any help to you? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html

Comment: thanks - this helps. Reading it leaves me with the problem of defining a "startup color" for the application, without that startup color being then inherited by every single view as it's background color :/